# prevent guest from creating topic but allow guest to reply the topic in wordpress using bbpress

Tags: php, wordpress, bbpress, forums

I am developing project in wordpress which uses bbpress plugin in wordpress.
I have used wordpress as alternative because in php we have to create forum ourself and it is time consuming.
I have successfully integrated bbpress and used it, but i want to chcange some configuration.
I have changed configuration of guest allow creating topic and replying to the topic, but i need different scenario.The guest can reply to the topic but cannot create topic.
thank in advance

Comment: I am also looing for the same functionality. But haven't come across any such plugin.

Comment: This is not the answer to your question, sorry.  But allowing a guest to comment will surely result in BAD BAD BAD consequences.  Bots and spammers will be filling up your database with unwanted comments.